# Strongswan tunnel is up but not pinging to each others

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

im facing weird problem i have configured site to site VPN tunnel on Centos 8 on the same network and its connected but unable to ping each others here is below my configuration and status.

Site A

[root@site-B ~]# strongswan status
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
2gateway-to-gateway1[4]: ESTABLISHED 6 seconds ago, 100.100.100.6[100.100.100.6]...100.100.100.22[100.100.100.22]
2gateway-to-gateway1{3}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 2, ESP SPIs: caeaf7b6_i c214a703_o
2gateway-to-gateway1{3}:   10.20.1.0/24 === 10.10.1.0/24

ip route

[root@site-A ~]# ip r show
default via 100.100.100.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 100
10.20.1.0/24 via 100.100.100.22 dev enp0s3
100.100.100.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 100.100.100.22 metric 100

```
onfig setup
    charondebug="all"
    uniqueids=yes
```

conn ateway1-to-gateway2
type=tunnel
auto=start
keyexchange=ikev2
authby=secret
left=100.100.100.22
leftsubnet=10.10.1.1/24
right=100.100.100.6
rightsubnet=10.20.1.1/24
ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
esp=aes256-sha1!
aggressive=no
keyingtries=%forever
ikelifetime=28800s
lifetime=3600s
dpddelay=30s
dpdtimeout=120s
dpdaction=restart

[root@site-A ~]# cat /etc/strongswan/ipsec.secrets
100.100.100.22  100.100.100.6 : PSK “XXXXXXXXXXXX”

```
[root@site-A ~]# cat /etc/sysctl.conf
```

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0

Site B

[root@site-B ~]# strongswan status
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
2gateway-to-gateway1[4]: ESTABLISHED 4 minutes ago, 100.100.100.6[100.100.100.6]...100.100.100.22[100.100.100.22]
2gateway-to-gateway1{3}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 2, ESP SPIs: caeaf7b6_i c214a703_o
2gateway-to-gateway1{3}:   10.20.1.0/24 === 10.10.1.0/24

IP route

[root@site-B ~]# ip r show
default via 100.100.100.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp metric 100
10.20.1.0/24 via 100.100.100.6 dev enp0s3
100.100.100.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 100.100.100.6 metric 100

```
config setup
    charondebug="all"
    uniqueids=yes
```

conn 2gateway-to-gateway1
type=tunnel
auto=start
keyexchange=ikev2
authby=secret
left=100.100.100.6
leftsubnet=10.20.1.1/24
right=100.100.100.22
rightsubnet=10.10.1.1/24
ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
esp=aes256-sha1!
aggressive=no
keyingtries=%forever
ikelifetime=28800s
lifetime=3600s
dpddelay=30s
dpdtimeout=120s
dpdaction=restart

[root@site-B ~]# cat /etc/strongswan/ipsec.secrets
100.100.100.6  100.100.100.22 : PSK “XXXXXXXXXXXXX”

```
[root@site-B ~]# cat /etc/sysctl.conf
```

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0

Answer (score 0):

Aoa, as your left and right subnets are on different networks so one solution is that:

1. Add gateway routes on both subnets and subnets start to pinging each other and then check encrypted packets between gateway devices.

Command:
route add x.x.x.0/24 mask x.x.x.x x.x.x.x(gw)